# Why does my sorting function output garbage values?

Tags: c, bubble-sort

- I'm working on a bubble sort but the length is completely off which starts printing garbage values like 0,1,2
- I've tried manipulating my conditional inside my for loop but it still outputs the garbage values

```
    
void bubbleSort(int array[], int len){
    int temp;
    int counter = -1; 
    printf("\n");
    while(counter != 0){
        counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //compare two ints swich the greater value to the right
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]){
                temp = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                counter++;
                //increment counter
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\nBubble Sort Completed\n");
}

int main(void){
    int a[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7 ,6, 8, 3, 9};
    int b[] = {10, 20, 40, 54, 23, 23, 12};
    size_t a_length =  sizeof(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    size_t b_length =  sizeof(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
    bubbleSort(a, a_length);
    bubbleSort(b, b_length);
}
```

My output usually looks like this

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Bubble Sort Completed

0 1 10 12 20 23 23 40 54
Bubble Sort Completed

1. Also just a little curious as to why the length of array b is equal to 8? Shouldn't the value be 7?

Comment: `array[i + 1]` in the sorting can be out-of-bounds. So will be the output from using `i <= len`. Check the loop limits in both cases.

Comment: @WeatherVane That makes sense but then shouldn't there be garbage values for the first bubble sort on array a?

Comment: Another error is `sizeof(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))` which should be `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` so you pass `8` to the function instead of `9`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) ` change it to `for (int i = 0; i < (len -1); i++) {` - stops running over the buffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least these problems:

Compare eventually accesses outside array bounds with `array[i + 1]` leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Anything may happen with UB.

```
    // Alternative code
    // for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        // if (array[i] > array[i + 1]){
        if (array[i-1] > array[i]){
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i-1];
            array[i-1] = temp;
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

... and ...

```
// for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("%i ", array[i]);
}
```

... and ...  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607348/why-does-my-sorting-function-output-garbage-values/69607423#comment123034215_69607348)

Wrong size calculation.

```
//size_t a_length =  sizeof(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
//size_t b_length =  sizeof(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
size_t a_length =  sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
size_t b_length =  sizeof b / sizeof b[0];
```

---

Also consider using same type in array indexing

```
// void bubbleSort(int array[], int len){
void bubbleSort(int array[], size_t len){

  size_t temp, counter;
  ...
```

Comment: This worked out great thanks a ton, I'm also super embarrassed that I completely glanced over the fact that I took the sizeof of sizeof 

Comment: Why do we want to use size_t compared to just storing it as an int value? Just kinda curious abt it.

Comment: @Crack09 The length of an array may exceed `INT_MAX`, thus `int` is not sufficient.  `size_t`, some _unsigned_ type,  is the designed to be sufficient for array indexing and sizing.  Note `sizeof` operator results in a `size_t`.  Should you could use `int`, or `short` or `char` to index, yet risk insufficent range.  Why do you want to use `int`?